# how to select employee in hql?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the scenario:

In a schedule I have `Appointments`, which contain a list of different `Services`. Each `Service` is related to an `Employee`, which is offers it.

The code looks something like this:

```
class Appointment extends BaseEntity{
    ...
    private List<Service> services;
    private Date start, end;
    ...
    // getter/setter
}

class Service extends BaseEntity{
    ...
    private Employee employee;
    ...
    // getter/setter
}

class Employee extends BaseEntity{
    ...
    private String id;
    ...
    // getter/setter
}
```

I want to write a query, which selects the `Employee` ids of all `Services`, which are offered in the `Appointments` in a specified time interval (from date1 to date2).

I tried several things, but I nothing was correct. My main problem is that I do not know how to correctly use the `List` in the `Appointment` and to connect this with the `Employee` id. I tried this, but it does not work:

"select e.id from Appointment a, Service s left join s.employee e where s in elements(a.services) and s.start <= date1 and s.end >= date2";

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following :

```
SELECT e.id 
FROM Appointment a 
INNER JOIN a.services s 
INNER JOIN s.employee e 
where s.start <= ? and s.end >= ?
```

Comment: I up-voted this, but can you please format your answer so we don't have to scroll?